# Join two tables on nearest matching string

Tags: mysql

I have a query_table Table and wants to join with match_table Table with nearest matching string. If it was vice-versa then 'like' would have worked but have no idea how to do this.

```
query_table
+----+------------------+
| id | string           |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | fcc9e8796feb     |
|  2 | fcdbd7ebcf89     |
|  3 | fccc87896feb     |
|  4 | fcc7c7896fef     |
|  5 | fcced777aaaf     |
+----+------------------+

match_table
+----+-----------+
| id | match_code|
+----+-----------+
|  1 | fcff      |
|  2 | fcccc     |
|  3 | fccc8     |
|  4 | fccc9     |
|  5 | fccdb     |
|  6 | fccdc     |
|  7 | fccd8     |
|  8 | fcce      |
|  9 | fcced     |
| 10 | fccee     |
| 11 | fcce6     |
| 12 | fcc7b     |
| 13 | fcc7c     |
| 14 | fcc8e     |
| 15 | fcc87     |
| 16 | fcc88     |
| 17 | fcc9e     |
| 18 | fcdbb     |
| 19 | fcdbc     |
| 20 | fcdbd     |
+----+-----------+
```

I expect

```
result
+----+------------------+----+----------------+
| id | string           | id | match_code     |
+----+------------------+----+----------------
|  1 | fcc9e8796feb     | 17 | fcc9e          |
|  2 | fcdbd7ebcf89     | 20 | fcdbd          |
|  3 | fccc87896feb     |  3 | fccc8          |
|  4 | fcc7c7896fef     | 13 | fcc7c          |
|  5 | fcced777aaaf     |  9 | fcced          |
+----+------------------+----+----------------+
```

Comment: What about id #5... it matches `fcce` and `fcced`

Comment: Its not a nearest match ... You mean you want to match `match_code` with the first 5 characters of `string` which is fairly simple

Comment: @SalmanA It supposed to match as max charters as it can. if we had ```fcced7``` in ```match_table``` then ```match_code``` would be ```fcced7```
@RiggsFolly Not first five characters but as max charters as it can match

Comment: @sachin I posted the answer based on that assumption